# AngularJs Jwt Auth

Tags: angularjs, jwt

I've setup a interceptor in AngularJs. Here I receive a token in the response. And I send one in my request. But when I refresh 2 times it goes so fast that I'm signed out.

```
employeeAppModule.config([
        '$httpProvider',
        function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
                var token, headers, $cookies;

                //inject cookies
                angular.injector(['ngCookies']).invoke(['$cookies', function(_$cookies_) {
                    $cookies = _$cookies_;
                }]);

                return {
                    request: function (request) {
                        token = $cookies.get('jwt-token');
                        headers = request.headers || (request.headers = {});
                        request.headers = headers;
                        if(token != null && token != 'undefined') {
                            request.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer' + token;
                        }

                        return request;
                    },
                    response: function (response) {
                        if (typeof response.data.result === 'undefined') {
                            return response;
                        }

                        if(response.status && response.status.code === 401) {
                            alert('token wordt verwijderd');
                        }

                        if(response.data && response.data.result.token && response.data.result.token.length > 10) {
                            $cookies.put('jwt-token', response.data.result.token);
                        }
                        return response;
                    }
                };
            });
        }]);
```

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with how fast you refresh the page. What happens with the `jwt-token` cookie when you're "signed out"? Do you remove it somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes when a user signs out the cookie will be removed.

Comment: What happens when you have a invalid token in your cookie? Your server returns 401 and then what? Does it automatically remove the token somewhere in that case? What response do you get back from the server when this signout happens?